# Laravel 5 - Check if date is today

Tags: laravel, date

I'm creating a timeline and I'm nearly finished. I want that the color of the date for each timeline event is the same beside if the date is "today".

So I need something like:

```
@if($event[$i]->created_at->format('d.m.Y') == *code or variable that says its today*)
     ....
@endif
```

But I couldn't figure out what I can do to save the todays date in a variable.. Does anybody knows a solution for this?

thanks!

Comment: Checking if its today it's a bit tricky. Consider timezones :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use [`isToday()`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) method to check if date is today:

```
if ($event[$i]->created_at->isToday())
```

Comment: isn't the isToday from laravel 5.3? I only have 5.1 :o

Comment: @WellNo, it's a Carbon method, not Laravel.

Comment: this works perfect :) both answers are working but I think that isToday() is the more comfortable way :)

Answer (score 6):

you can use Carbon

```
 @if($event[$i]->created_at->format('d.m.Y') == \Carbon::today() )
 ....
 @endif
```

Comment: I will try that, give me a seccond :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use
whereDate, whereMonth, whereDay, whereYear, whereTime

whereDate()

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->whereDate('created_at', '2019-11-31')
        ->get();
```

whereMonth()

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->whereMonth('created_at', '10')
        ->get();
```

whereDay()

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->whereDay('created_at', '20')
        ->get();
```

whereYear()

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->whereYear('created_at', '2019')
        ->get();
```

whereTime()

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->whereTime('created_at', '=', '11:20:45')
        ->get();
```